# What transformation of raw sensor values from Sentinel-2 is GEE using?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, satellite

What transformation of raw values obtained from Sentinel-2's sensors is Google Earth Engine using?
When accessing the data from the Sentinel Hub directly, the values that I get are a bit different than those obtained from GEE ...

Images below show the difference. Does anybody know why this is the case?

**Raw data from Sentinel Hub**

[image]

**GEE data**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they are both the same processing level?